# How to call onclicklistner of animated image android

Tags: android, image, animation

i am working on android app
in which i have an animated image.
my code is

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth()/2;
left = new TranslateAnimation(0, hight, width, hight);
left1= new TranslateAnimation( 480, 10, 0, 10);
left.setDuration(2000);
left.setAnimationListener(this);
b1 =(ImageView)findViewById( R.id.balloon);
b1.setOnClickListener(this);
b1.startAnimation(left);


@Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
  Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked", 27).show();
}
```

using this code i am able to animate ballon or my picture but i the onclick lisnter only works when animation is completed i want onclicklistner should work during animation how to do this.
sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override  `onAnimationStart` and `onAnimationEnd` functions in your `AnimationListener`. Keep a variable to check whether animation is playing when the image clicked.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageView imageView;
    private boolean animationPlaying;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation( 480, 10, 0, 10);
        animation.setDuration(2000);
        animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                animationPlaying = true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                animationPlaying = false;
            }
        });

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imageView.startAnimation(animation);

        imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(animationPlaying) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Log.d("ANIMATION", "click missed because animation was not playing");
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: I have added a complete example.